# Steps for successful image recognition

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I have been doing image processing and machine learning course for couple of weeks . Everyday I learn something new about image manipulation and as well as how to train a system to recognize patterns in an image .
My question is in order to do successful image recognition what are the steps one has to follow ,for example denoising , use of LDA , PCA , then use of neural network . I am not looking for any algorithm , just a brief outline of each of the steps(5 -6) from capturing an image to test an input image for similarity.

P.S# To the mods , before labelling this question as not constructive , I know its not constructive , but I don't know which site to put this so . So please redirect me that site of stackexchange .

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate (cross-post): http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10048/steps-for-successful-image-recognition

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about image processing rather than programming and is better suited to http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe the pipeline as follows, and I omitted many bullet items.

1. acquire images with ground truth labeling.

   - amazon M-turk
   - image and label from flickr
2. compute feature for that image

   - direct stretch the image as a column vector
   - use more complicated features such as bag of words, LBP.
3. post-process the features to reduce the effect of noise if needed

   - sparse coding
   - max pooling
   - whitening
4. train a classifier/regressor given the (feature,label) pair

   - SVM
   - boosting
   - neural network
   - random forest
   - spectral clustering
   - heuristic methods...
5. use the trained model to recognize the unseen images and evaluate the result with some metrics.

BTW. traditionally, we will use dimension reduction methods such as PCA to make the problem tractable, but recent research seems cares nothing about that.

Comment: Where does finding region of interest fits in . I am currently working on medical imaging , so the data is not properly normalized . Some pictures are zoomed in for clarity , some of them contains clothes , skin and then affected region . I have heard about SIFT , does it have to do anything here . Moreover , while using step 4 , do I have to use all of them ?

Comment: And what is amazon M-turk

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate some of the points such as calculating features of that image .

Comment: Close enough ...since nobody had a better answer ,so .

Answer (score 2):

Few months back I developed a face recognition system using local binary pattern.
In this method I first took a image either from local storage or camera, then using local binary pattern method I considered each block of the input image. After getting LBP of input image, I found chi-square distance for lbp feature histogram. comparing its value with the stored database image using same process. I was able to get same face.

Answer (score 1):

amazon M-turk is a service to make people do work for you. (and you pay them)

SIFT is a descriptor for interest points. By comparing those descriptors, you can find the correspondence between images. (SIFT fits into step 2.)

when doing step 4. you can choose to combines the result of different classifier, or simply trust the result of one classifier. That depends on situation.

Are you going to label the location of affected region? I am not sure what you are going to do.

couldn't use comment so I post another answer.

Comment: This is probably for my undergrad thesis , I basically have a database of ~8000 images of skin diseases . Each disease has on average 40 to 50 image . Problem is I know how to do normal image processing ( e.g digit recognition) . The database I have have the diseased region of several patients , and all the diseased region are not from the same part of the body , some are zoomed , some are zoomed out . Question is what sort of segmentation algorithm will help , or will sift be able to identify the region e.g http://www.atlasdermatologico.com.br/listar.asp?acao=mostrar&arquivo=acne7.jpg ;

Comment: You should separate the problem into detection and segmentation. For detection, you have to build a classifier and let it scan over the spatial space and scale space of the input image. After those disease locations are found, do the segmentation algorithm. SIFT is not a good feature for this problem. Try "bag of words" model instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more . I am less willing to take a shot in the dark . Just stressing you a little .